# Php code to import data to wordpress post from plain mysql database

Tags: wordpress, import, web-crawler, posts

I have a database with contents ( that I crawled from other sources then save to MySql Database ) then I want to make some php to get data from that database to insert as posts to Wordpress database.

Anyone have any experience in this case before ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin which will read data from your table where all crawled data is saved and use this function to insert wp_insert_post https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ then your crawled data is inserting as wordpress posts

Comment: $id = wp_insert_post(array('post_title'=>'random', 'post_type'=>'custom_post', 'post_content'=>'demo text'));